# c# - Do you need a DataTable to retrieve data from a DataAdapter?

Tags: c#, sql, datatable

Most of my queries are very short, 1-3 records total.  This is the code I have now.  I am wondering if there is a way to capture userid directly from DataAdapter without going through a table.  Thanks!

```
    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, strCon);
    SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
    DataTable t = new DataTable();
    dataAdapter.Fill(t);
    int userid = 0;
    if (t.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        DataRow dr = t.Rows[0];
        userid = dr.Field<int>(0);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have only one return value, you can use [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) and you have [ExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k) to get multiple return values.

Here's the msdn sample:

```
private static void CreateCommand(string queryString,
    string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
               connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader[0]));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a reader:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.80).aspx

Quicker and less resources 1 record or hundreds.